# React Native, importing routes.js in app.js giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm importing my routes.js in my app.js but it's throwing error that `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function` but I'm importing and exporting it correctly then why it's showing that error, can anyone please help? below is my code

routes.js

```
const RoutesContainer = data => {
  let intial_Route = 'AuthStack';
  if (data.isLogin) {
    intial_Route =
      data.userType == USER_TYPE.PLAYER ? 'PlayerStack' : 'CoachStack';
  }

  return createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        AuthStack,
        CoachStack,
        PlayerStack,
      },
      {initialRouteName: intial_Route},
    ),
  );
};

export default RoutesContainer;
```

that's my routes.js, I'm pretty sure it's correct

app.js

```
import RoutesContainer from './src/Routes';

render() {
    const {isLogin, userType} = this.state;
    const Routes = RoutesContainer({isLogin, userType});
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <Routes
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
        <FlashMessage position="top" />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

that's my app.js

Comment: Whats the version of navigation that you are using ?

Comment: i'm using 4.0 version

Comment: try the pattern AuthStack:{screen:AuthStack}

Comment: inside createSwitchNavigator?

Comment: Yes can you try that n see for all routes ?

Comment: I tried in createSwitch but same error wait i will update my question and add full code of route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223691/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-dark-prince).